# php-serial not working

Tags: php, windows, serial-port, arduino

I am trying to use PHP to make my Arduino send out a signal. Whenever I run the code below, it says "Invalid serial port", though it is valid?

```
<?php

include 'serial_connect.php';

$serial = new phpSerial;

$serial->deviceSet("COM2");

$serial->deviceOpen();

$serial->sendMessage("1000");

$serial->deviceClose();
?>
```

The serial_connect.php class is php-serial, link here: http://www.phpclasses.org/package/3679-PHP-Communicate-with-a-serial-port.html

Here is my Arduino sketch:

```
int ledPin = 13;

void setup() {
    pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);
    Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
    if(Serial.available() > 0) {
        int time = Serial.parseInt();        
        digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);
        delay(time);
        digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);
    }
}
```

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Do you have the right permissions to access COM2? I guess the host is a windows machine?

Comment: 1. I'm not sure, and I'm not sure how to check either. 2. Yes it is a windows machine.

Answer (score 2):

Check that your COM2 is installed, enabled, and working right in device manager, if you haven't. Also what model of Arduino are you using? I don't think this question can be answered without more information. It might be wise to add that info to your original question. Also, we can't see the source of the php_serial class without registering for an account, which I do not wish to do.
I realize this is more of a comment than an answer, but I need a bit more rep to comment (a flaw in S.O.'s reputation system, in my opinion.) But the original question will not get an answer without more information, so I felt it was pertinent to add. Best of luck.

Answer (score 2):

You're not setting a baud rate in the PHP code.

Have you tried using a terminal emulator (like Hyperterm) to confirm that your serial port is wired up correctly?

You might need to use the string `\\.\COM2` as the name of the serial port -- that's what I do in a C program I wrote.  Note that you will probably need to escape those backslashes: `"\\\\.\\COM2"`.

Comment: I'll go set the baud rate now, and I have been using the port with java for some time now and I am sure it works, and I'll try those serial ports.

Answer (score 0):

there are several bugs in the PHP-serial class code.

function DeviceSet
does not work on linux for ttyUSB0 or ttyACM0 out of the box;

function confstopbits,
the if for $this->os===osx needs to be an ELSEIF

And then still, when trying to connect to an Arduino from a PI or BBB, you'll need to 
stty -F /dev/ttyACM0 ignpar
to get it to work properly...

Comment: Please, add some tags, and exact examples what did you try. Also read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask